# .NET Webbrowser control with additional headers

Tags: vb.net, browser

I am using a webbrowser control and loading a website that uses basic authentication.  I pass the username and password in the additional header of the navigate routine.  The problem is that the header is not retained while navigating the site.

I.E.
I log into the site and pass the user name and password in the http header.  When I click a link to access another page the header is removed and the site asks for credentials.  If I was to just type the site into IE and log in the first time the headers are carried forward on all pages.

Anybody have any ideas how I can have the page retain the headers so the user never has to authenticate?

```
Dim sHeaders As String
Dim HelpBrowser As New WebBrowser

sHeaders = "Authorization: Basic: " & System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("UserName:Password")) & Chr(13) & Chr(10)

Me.HelpBrowser.Navigate("http://www.mysite.com", True, Nothing, sHeaders)
```

Comment: Where is the other page displayed? a window in your program or in  a new tab in IE?

Comment: Have you found any solution? I have the same problem. Start a new navigation is not working for me...

Answer (score 3):

Suppose the user name and password for authentication is user1 and pass1. Use the following statement to provide basic auth information that will not be lost after redirection:

```
Me.HelpBrowser.Navigate("http://user1:pass1@www.mysite.com")
```

Answer (score 2):

Passing credentials in the URL has been disabled by default in IE per KB834489.

A registry change must be made to allow this kind of navigation:

To disable the new default behavior in Windows Explorer and Internet Explorer, create `iexplorer.exe` and `explorer.exe` DWORD values in one of the following registry keys and set their value data to 0.

•For all users of the program, set the value in the following registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_HTTP_USERNAME_PASSWORD_DISABLE
```

•For the current user of the program only, set the value in the following registry key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_HTTP_USERNAME_PASSWORD_DISABLE
```

For more information, see:
http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;[LN];834489

Answer (score 0):

The following is in c#, but I would hope there is a similar Navigating event for vb.  I found that to be able to navigate the site without the Authorization Header getting lost or removed I had to do the following otherwise for each new page the user was prompted again.  This solution also does not require the user:password@site syntax to be enabled.

```
    private bool _redirected = false;
    private const string BaseUrl = @"http://mySite";

    private void Navigate()
    {
        var helpUrl = BaseUrl;
        var authHeader = GetAuthHeader();

        _docWindow.Browser.Navigate(helpUrl, string.Empty, null, authHeader);           
        _docWindow.Browser.Navigating += Browser_Navigating;

    }

    private string GetAuthHeader()
    {
        byte[] authData = UnicodeEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_userName + ":" + _password);
        string authHeader = "Authorization: Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(authData);
        return authHeader;
    }

    void Browser_Navigating(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
    {            
        if (_redirected)
        {
            _redirected = false;
            return;
        }
        var newPage = BaseUrl + e.Uri.AbsolutePath;

        e.Cancel = true;
        _redirected = true;
        _docWindow.Browser.Navigate(newPage, string.Empty, null, GetAuthHeader());
    }
```